# How to make square legend in google chart?

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization, legend, pie-chart

i am new to angularjs and google charts ,i make a pie chart using google chart but by default it show the legend in circle form but i want to make it in square how this can be done.
also if  legend label  is lengthy i.e "software and hardware stores" then it not shown in one line the software on first line on second line hardware and son on.
i want to make it aligned with the legend signe it should be displayed on one line.
here is my code in Index.HTML:

```
         <head>
           <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>
           <script src="script.js"></script>
           <script src="http://bouil.github.io/angular-google-chart/ng-google-chart.js"></script>
         </head>

         <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
           <div style="padding-left:100px">
                my pig pie chart</div>
         <div google-chart chart="chart" style="width:400,height:300"></div>
         </body>
```

Script.js:

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', [ 'googlechart' ]);

     app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      var chart1 = {};
      chart1.type = "PieChart";
      chart1.data = [
       ['Component', 'cost'],
       ['Software hardware and electrice', 50000],
       ['Hardware', 80000]
  ];
       chart1.data.push(['Services',20000]);
        chart1.options = {
       'legend':'right',
        'width':400,
        'height':300
   };
  chart1.formatters = {
      number : [{
      columnNum: 1,
      pattern: "$ #,##0.00"
    }]
  };

   $scope.chart = chart1;

     $scope.aa=1*$scope.chart.data[1][1];
    $scope.bb=1*$scope.chart.data[2][1];
    $scope.cc=1*$scope.chart.data[3][1];
});
```

any suggestion guide me how can i do this.thanks

Comment: Please ask one question per question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to increase the width of the chart until all the text fits on one line.  Since the pie chart wants to stay centered you need something like 1000px wide with 300px tall. If you play with the chart area options you might be able to get away with a lot less.

Another option is to set `legend.position='bottom'`. This makes all the legend items line up in a row underneath the chart. In this case if your string is too long for the size of the chart, then it will truncate your string, but it doesn't need as wide a total space as making the whole chart very wide.

Comment: one more thing how can i change the legend style it by default is circle for pie chart i want to make it square